# Is it possible to randomly play audio files using a vector with random_shuffle?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to randomly play wav files on a continuous loop.

Can I use something like this code below and input the wav file names in the array in place of the integers? I know I would need to change the vector type from int to string. And then use the PlaySound function to play the files?

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto ints = std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    auto rng = std::default_random_engine {};
    std::shuffle(ints.begin(), ints.end(), rng);

    for (auto&& i : ints) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Here is my new code:

```
int main() {
    string audio = "audio.wav";
    string audio2 = "audio2.wav";
    string audio3 = "audio3.wav";
    auto ints = std::vector<string> { "audio.wav", "audio2.wav", "audio3.wav" };

    auto rng = std::default_random_engine {};
    std::shuffle(ints.begin(), ints.end(), rng);

    for (auto i : ints) {
        PlaySound("audio.wav", NULL, SND_SYNC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not? Have you tried calling that function?

Comment: I've only been learning to code for 5 days, so I really don't know what I'm doing. I have tried calling the PlaySound function and it works without the vector, so I can play a single audio file. I'm trying to get it working with this vector, though, so I can randomly play a bunch of different audio files.

Comment: @22878 So how are you calling the `PlaySound()` function depending on these random integers?

Comment: You don't need to use `auto &&` in the loop. You may need to use `const auto &` if you don't want to copy the array element (e.g. when it is large) or `auto &` if you want to modify elements. But `int` is small and you don't need to modify the elements. So just `auto i` or `int i`.

Comment: @aparpara It looks slightly weird, but here `auto &&` is no different from `auto &`, since it acts as an universal reference.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, you can. And you don't need to shuffle the actual filenames, you can shuffle integers and use them as indices in the filename vector. Only the smallest integer should be 0, or the first track will be never played.

Like this:

```
for (auto i : ints) {
    std::cout << filenames[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my code in my question. It will repeat the one audio file, but I don't know how to implement the array into the PlaySound function. Can I use the array index somehow to play the files randomly?